# Protractor Image didnt upload on dialogue box?

Tags: css, angular, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I want to test the image upload functionality using Protractor but my written script didnt work.
[This is the image dialogue box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNvdr.png)When we click on the dialogue box image it open the window to select desired image.After the selection of image,the box acts like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxPtj.png).I want to write a script through which i can upload an image and then click on the "Save" button.[This is the css of dialogue box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frjtt.png) 
Given below is the script that i tried but doesn't work. The error message that encountered is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gBBg.png).

```
   var path = require('path');
   var fileToUpload = '../new image.jpeg';
    var absolutePath = path.resolve('__dirname', fileToUpload);
    console.log(absolutePath);
 var fileElem=element(by.css('label[for="cropper-file-input"]'));
 browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(fileElem), 2000,);
 fileElem.sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below method. Hope it may help you.

```
 fileUpload(element: ElementFinder, fileElem: ElementFinder, filePath: string): promise.Promise<void> {
        //We are using the setFileDetector method to let WebDriver know that we are uploading files from a local directory to a remote server.
        //Having this configuration resolves the "Failed: invalid argument: File not found" error that occurs otherwise.
        browser.driver.setFileDetector(new utils.remote.FileDetector);

        return browser.executeScript(`arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.height = '1px'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px';  arguments[0].style.opacity = 1`, element)
            .then(() => fileElem.sendKeys(filePath));
    }
```

Comment: what is meant by 'element' in given function...as got error while running this script.

Comment: The element you perform click action to choose the file.